# How to write the documentation for my own class

Tags: documentation

Some time ago I started to create my own class and these moments my purpose is to create the documentation. I would like to know if to create the documentation of my class I should be guided by this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Package_Documentation) or simply create a document using LaTeX and explaining the code.

---

I also found the following documentation [How to Package Your LaTeX Package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf) that has been very useful for me, but still I do not understand how from my class `myclass.cls` I can generate the documentation using dtx. I also tried to use the `skeleton A.4` mentioned in the previous link but I get the error `!LaTeX Error: File myclass.dtx not found.`

Thank you all for your suggestions and answers.

Comment: I'd choose the second way. I love the simple. But this is opinion-based. You can choose whatever you want.

Comment: The advantage of dtx is it is a common format that everyone understands, and encourages you to have your comments alongside your code.  The disadvantage is that you have to understand the two or three different outputs that a dtx file can have.

Comment: I really would like to learn about dtx, could you tell me some source of information, examples, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/05/the-dtx-format/ and https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/ are two great posts to get you started. My feeling is that `.dtx` is extremely useful if you want to document your code/implementation. For user-level documentation `.dtx` is not always that advantageous (depending on your project), because the order and explanations of the implementation may not follow the 'natural flow' you would want your usage documentation to have. In that case the `.dtx` is still a nice way to pack up everything in one file, though (if you like that sort of thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that this is opinion based but I like the `doc`  (aka `dtx`) (`> texdoc doc`) system for specifying and documenting LaTeX class and package code. In one document you can have the code, explanations of the code, a user manual, and other related things. If you ever have to update something then it can all be done in one file.

As an aside, in the past, I have used extensions to the `doc` system for documenting MetaPost, C, Java, and EXPRESS code.